# Insert into Select only inserts one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to convert an XML file to a MS SQL Server Table but it only inserts the first row. Can anyone explain this please?

I am using insert select to import the data. I have tried everything but the code is so stripped down and I can't see how to fix this.

```
    CREATE DATABASE lei_1
    GO

    USE lei_1
    GO

    CREATE TABLE lei_1_table
    (
        Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        XMLData XML,
        LoadedDateTime DATETIME
    )

    CREATE TABLE recordsx
    ( 
        LegalName VARCHAR(100),
        la_Line1 [varchar](100),
        la_Line2 [varchar](100),
        la_City [varchar](100),
        la_Region [varchar](100),
        la_Country [varchar](100),
        la_PostalCode [varchar](100)
    );

    INSERT INTO lei_1_table(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\lei_example2.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

    SELECT * FROM lei_1_table

    DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)


    SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM lei_1_table


    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML, '<lei:LEIData xmlns:lei="http://www.leiroc.org/data/schema/leidata/2014" />'

    SELECT LegalName, la_Line1, la_Line2, la_City, la_Region, la_Country, la_PostalCode
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'lei:LEIData')
    WITH 
    (
        LegalName [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalName',
        la_Line1 [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Line1',
        la_Line2 [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Line2',
        la_City [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:City',
        la_Region [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Region',
        la_Country [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Country',
        la_PostalCode [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:PostalCode'
    )

    insert into recordsx(LegalName, la_Line1, la_Line2, la_City, la_Region, la_Country, la_PostalCode)
    SELECT LegalName, la_Line1, la_Line2, la_City, la_Region, la_Country, la_PostalCode FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'lei:LEIData')
    WITH 
    (
        LegalName [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalName',
        la_Line1 [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Line1',
        la_Line2 [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Line2',
        la_City [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:City',
        la_Region [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Region',
        la_Country [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Country',
        la_PostalCode [varchar](100) 'lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:PostalCode'
    )

    SELECT * FROM recordsx


    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
    GO
```

Here's my XML:

```
<lei:LEIData xmlns:lei="http://www.leiroc.org/data/schema/leidata/2014">             
  <lei:LEIRecords>
<lei:LEIRecord>
  <lei:LEI>48510000JZ17NWGUA510</lei:LEI>
  <lei:Entity>
    <lei:LegalName>KDD - Centralna klirin</lei:LegalName>
    <lei:LegalAddress>
      <lei:Line1>Tivolska cesta 48</lei:Line1>
      <lei:City>Ljubljana</lei:City>
      <lei:Country>SI</lei:Country>
      <lei:PostalCode>1000</lei:PostalCode>
    </lei:LegalAddress>
  </lei:Entity>
</lei:LEIRecord>
<lei:LEIRecord>
  <lei:LEI>485100004VOFFO18DD84</lei:LEI>
  <lei:Entity>
    <lei:LegalName>NLB VITljana</lei:LegalName>
    <lei:LegalAddress>
      <lei:Line1>Trg republike 3</lei:Line1>
      <lei:City>Ljubljana</lei:City>
      <lei:Country>SI</lei:Country>
      <lei:PostalCode>1000</lei:PostalCode>
    </lei:LegalAddress>
  </lei:Entity>
</lei:LEIRecord>
  </lei:LEIRecords>
</lei:LEIData>
```

Comment: You need to show your xml.

Comment: Well your example seems to load everything just fine. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Thanks, when I run it in MS SQL Server it only creates the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you select xpath too shallow. Following query returns 2 lines from you xml.

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML, '<lei:LEIData xmlns:lei="http://www.leiroc.org/data/schema/leidata/2014" />'

SELECT LegalName, la_Line1, la_Line2, la_City, la_Region, la_Country, la_PostalCode                      
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'lei:LEIData/lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord')
WITH                          --^ here
(
    LegalName [varchar](100) 'lei:Entity/lei:LegalName',
    la_Line1 [varchar](100) 'lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Line1',
    la_Line2 [varchar](100) 'lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Line2',
    la_City [varchar](100) 'lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:City',
    la_Region [varchar](100) 'lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Region',
    la_Country [varchar](100) 'lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Country',
    la_PostalCode [varchar](100) 'lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:PostalCode'
)

--insert into recordsx(LegalName, la_Line1, la_Line2, la_City, la_Region, la_Country, la_PostalCode)
SELECT LegalName, la_Line1, la_Line2, la_City, la_Region, la_Country, la_PostalCode 
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'lei:LEIData/lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord/lei:Entity')
WITH                          --^ here
(
    LegalName [varchar](100) 'lei:LegalName',
    la_Line1 [varchar](100) 'lei:LegalAddress/lei:Line1',
    la_Line2 [varchar](100) 'lei:LegalAddress/lei:Line2',
    la_City [varchar](100) 'lei:LegalAddress/lei:City',
    la_Region [varchar](100) 'lei:LegalAddress/lei:Region',
    la_Country [varchar](100) 'lei:LegalAddress/lei:Country',
    la_PostalCode [varchar](100) 'lei:LegalAddress/lei:PostalCode'
)

--SELECT * FROM recordsx


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Additionally, if you declare `@xml` as `XML` type then you can use native xml methods like `.nodes()` and so on.
To say truth in my experience these native methods are slower than `openxml` you use.

Example of native xml methods.

```
--from OP
DECLARE @XML AS XML
SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM lei_1_table

--@xml is already xml type. So use it.
--honor xmlns:lei="..." but not necessarily under the same name
;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.leiroc.org/data/schema/leidata/2014' as x)
--insert tbl goes here
--note [1]. value() requires a singleton
select t.v.value('../x:LEI[1]','varchar(100)') LEI -- note ../ for parent node
   ,t.v.value('x:LegalName[1]','varchar(100)') LegalName
   ,t.v.value('(x:LegalAddress/x:Line1)[1]','varchar(100)') Line1
   ,t.v.value('(x:LegalAddress/x:Line2)[1]','varchar(100)') Line2
   ,t.v.value('(x:LegalAddress/x:City)[1]','varchar(100)') City
   ,t.v.value('(x:LegalAddress/x:Region)[1]','varchar(100)') Region
   ,t.v.value('(x:LegalAddress/x:Country)[1]','varchar(100)') Country
   ,t.v.value('(x:LegalAddress/x:PostalCode)[1]','varchar(100)') PostalCode
from @xml.nodes('x:LEIData/x:LEIRecords/x:LEIRecord/x:Entity') t(v)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you @AlexKudryashev

Answer (score 0):

This is because your query is ONLY ever going to get a single row with the entire contents of the file.

Looking at the documentation from MS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

> SINGLE_CLOB By reading data_file as ASCII, returns the contents as a
>   single-row, single-column rowset of type varchar(max), using the
>   collation of the current database.

My guess is you will need to shred that xml during your insert.

Comment: Thanks but I already shredded it using the built in TSQL stored procedure sp_xml_preparedocument